# Listview setting rows using adapter

Tags: android, listview

I am having a `listview` and each row is having an image, some `textviews`. 
Now, some of the rows will not be having some `textviews` depends upon the conditions in the code.
I am using `viewHolder` for this, so when I am applying condition for visibility, these options get disappear in the rows where they should appear.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: You need to share your code so that people can help.

Comment: please add your code here..

Answer (score 0):

This is common mistake. You might have added code to hide `TextView` for certain condition. You have to add code to show `TextView` if condition is not met.

Eg.

```
if (condition) {
        textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

This happens because `ListView` [recycles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14108676/3843374) rows to work more efficiently, and faster.